# Como puedo recorrer todos los registros de dos query al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, mysql

Como pudiera recorrer correctamente con un loop todos los registros de 2 querys(al mismo tiempo) que estan almacenados en 2 arrays asociativos(mysql_fecth_assoc) y compararlos con la funcion array_diff(array1,array2).

Lo hice asi y solo carga( y compara bien) los valores de ambos arrays en el primer registro de cada uno, luego solo carga los valores del array1 y no recorre el array2.

```
<?php do {
$arr = array_diff($array1,$array2)
foreach ($arr as $value) {
        echo $value.' '.'<br>';}}
while($array1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($variable_query))?>
```

Comment: Como nota no relacionada con tu pregunta directamente: deberías evitar usar los métodos mysql_* porque se consideran obsoletos desde PHP 5.5 y se eliminaron en PHP 7. Son potencialmente menos seguros y hacen el código menos robusto y portable.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que primero que comparar si los dos arrays son del mismo tamaño, luego recorrerlos por la llave algo asi como

```
for($x =0;$x < count($array1);$x++){
   if($array1[$x] != $array2){
      //todo
   }
}
```

o bueno, primero que es lo que buscas hacer ?, porque **array_diff** solo regresa el valor que no se encontró en el segundo array